# elasticsearch/mongoosastic : what is the differences between es_indexed and es_type

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I needed to implement search in an app i found elasticsearcha and the mongoosastic as am using mongoose to CRUD my mongodb.

Follow the steps provided [here](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic) indexing many fields in a model and everything works fine. but before i put this in action i wanted to figure out what the difference between

```
title: {type: String, es_indexed:true}
description: {type: String, es_type:'string'}
```

iv'e also figure out using `es_boost:2.0` for example give high proiorty.

```
string: {type:String, es_boost:2.0}
```